# jquery loop for datapicker

Tags: jquery, loops

Hi
I'd like add datepicker for 10 fields. Each field's name/id begins with "datazatr" and ends with number from 1 to 10. I've put it in the loop, but it doesn't work - datapicker doesn't load in any of these fields.

Here's the code:

```
  $(function() {
    for (var i = 1, i < 11; i++) {
        $( "#datazatr" + i ).datepicker();
    }
  });
```

What should I change to make it work?
Thanks for your help

//second script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#nowikons_dodaj').validate({
    rules: {
        imie1: {
            required: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $("#nazwisko1").is(":filled");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: whether the input elements are present in the dom when your script is executed

Comment: put this before the loop and show us the result : `alert( $( "#datazatr0").length)`

Comment: They should be present. $(function() .. ) is on document ready - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: alert( $( "#datazatr1").length) - for each field from 1 to 10 it alert shows "1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use **[attribute startwith](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** selector instead of looping through all the elements,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("[id^=datazatr]").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Just to be clear - this finds all the fields which id starts with "datazatr" and add datepicker to them? That's very useful :)

Comment: yes you are right.. it will pick all the elements with id starts with datazatr

Comment: One more question. I'd like to run script for each field which id begins with "imie" and ends with numbers 1 to 10. Each field "imie" depends on field "nazwisko" with the same number at the end eg. "imie6" depends on "nazwisko6". I added this script to my first post as "second script". What can I do?

Comment: It would be bette if you give class name to the first one

Comment: Can you give me an example how it should look like? I'm kinda new in all that stuff, so I'm sorry if my questions are "easy"... :)

Comment: can you make it as another question with the required html tags? I will help you on that.

Comment: Yes, but I had to add a new topic for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376103/jquery-loop-for-script