# jquery loop for script

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I'd like to run script for each field which id begins with "imie" and ends with numbers 1 to 10. Each field "imie" depends on field "nazwisko" with the same number at the end eg. "imie6" depends on "nazwisko6".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#nowikons_dodaj').validate({
rules: {
    imie1: {
        required: {
            depends: function (element) {
                return $("#nazwisko1").is(":filled");
            }
        }
    }
}
});
});
```

Here's also html/php code for these fields:
`for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td>";
   echo "<td><input type='text' name='nazwisko".$i."' id='nazwisko".$i."'></td>";
   echo "<td><input type='text' name='imie".$i."' id='imie".$i."'></td>";}`

Answer (score 1):

If you colud give class name to `imie` element which is same as the id of `nazwisko` element, it would be easy. Then the code will be

```
$("[id^=imie]").change(function () {

alert($("." + this.id).val());

});
```

**HTML**

```
<td><input type='text' name='nazwisko1' id='nazwisko1'></td>
<td><input type='text' class="nazwisko1" name='imie1' id='imie1'></td>
```

Comment: @katrinaaa90 let me know if you want any additional assistance

Answer (score -1):

You'd be better off putting a validation function on the blur event of those fields. For example

```
$('#thatTable').on('blur', 'input.imie', function(evt) {
    var nazwisko = $(this).parent(td).prev('td').find('input.nazwisko');
    //now do so something with nazwisko's data
});
```

This assumes you add a CSS class to each field to help the jQuery selector.